# How to get the Total count without distinct?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

**Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=1458cfa2dbed71a967ec6c9b86f7a612)**

I have a table as

`TABLE_MAIN`

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| id  | name     | phase   |
+-----+----------+---------+
| 101 | Bolt     | PHASE 1 |
| 102 | Nut      | PHASE 1 |
| 103 | Screw    | PHASE 2 |
| 104 | Hex BOLT | PHASE 2 |
| 105 | Rubber   | PHASE 3 |
| 106 | Aluminum | PHASE 3 |
| 107 | Slate    | PHASE 3 |
| 108 | Pen      | PHASE 3 |
| 109 | Pencil   | PHASE 3 |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

`TABLE_ERROR`

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| id  | name     | phase   |
+-----+----------+---------+
| 101 | Bolt     | PHASE 1 |
| 102 | Needle   | PHASE 1 |
| 101 | Bolt     | PHASE 3 |
| 102 | Needle   | PHASE 3 |
| 104 | Bolt     | PHASE 3 |
| 105 | Rubber   | PHASE 3 |
| 105 | Plastic  | PHASE 3 |
| 106 | Aluminum | PHASE 3 |
| 106 | Steel    | PHASE 3 |
| 106 | Cooper   | PHASE 3 |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

Now I'm trying to find the number of times the ID of `PHASE 3` in `table_error` appearing in `table_main` for each phase. If the ID is repeating, It should get added to the total count.

Expected

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| phase   | already_present | total |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| PHASE 1 | 2               | 8     |
| PHASE 2 | 1               | 8     |
| PHASE 3 | 5               | 8     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

I have tried

```
SELECT phase, count(*) AS already_present, sum(count(*)) OVER () AS total
FROM table_main
WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM table_error
        WHERE phase = 'PHASE 3'
        )
GROUP BY phase
```

But it is giving me,

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| phase   | already_present | total |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
| PHASE 1 | 2               | 5     |
| PHASE 2 | 1               | 5     |
| PHASE 3 | 2               | 5     |
+---------+-----------------+-------+
```

Comment: Why do you expect PHASE 2 to return an already_present of 1? Is (104, 'Bolt', 'PHASE 3') in table_error an error?

Comment: If you take the ID's of `PHASE 3` in `error_table`, those will be `101,102,104,105,105,106,106,106`. In this list, `101 & 102` are from `PHASE 1` hence count is 2 for `PHASE 1` and then `104` is from `PHASE 2`, so the count for `PHASE 2` is 1 and others(`105,105,106,106,106`) are from `PHASE 3`.Hence that count for `PHASE 3`is 5 @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
    select tm.phase, count(tm.id) AS already_present, SUM(count(tm.id)) OVER() as total
    from table_main tm
    inner join table_error te on te.id = tm.id and te.phase = 'PHASE 3'
    group by tm.phase
```